# cannot compile openssh due to OpenSSL library not found

Tags: openssl, openssh

I am based on 16.04, trying to install openssh from source

```
sudo apt install -y build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev
wget "http://mirrors.evowise.com/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-7.4p1.tar.gz"
tar xfz openssh-7.4p1.tar.gz
cd openssh-7.4p1
./configure
```

When trying to configure, I've gotten the following error message:

```
checking OpenSSL header version... 10101000 (OpenSSL 1.1.1-dev  xx XXX xxxx)
checking OpenSSL library version... not found
configure: error: OpenSSL library not found.
```

checking the path  **/usr/local/ssl# ls** shows the following files

certs            ct_log_list.cnf.dist  openssl.cnf       private
ct_log_list.cnf  misc                  openssl.cnf.dist

i don't know why it doesn't find the openssl library while I have already installed the libssl library.

how to solve it

Comment: Try `configure --help`. Pay attention to `--with-openssl-dir` and `--with-zlib`. The last time I checked OpenSSH does not build against OpenSSL 1.1.0. Also see OpenSSH [PR 48, Make it build using OpenSSL 1.1.0](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/pull/48). If this is your problem, then you should drop back to OpenSSL 1.0.2. Also see [OpenSSL 1.1.0 Changes](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_1.1.0_Changes) on the OpenSSL wiki. Finally, I believe OpenSSL 7.6p1 is the latest.

Comment: You might also be interested in [Noloader Build-Scripts](https://github.com/noloader/Build-Scripts). It can build OpenVPN for you using the latest OpenSSL 1.0.2.

Comment: any solution for this?   I get the same error, I have openssl 1.0.2o installed and I'm adding `--with-ssl-dir=/usr/local/openssl-1.0.2o` to the configure flag.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to cross-compile openSSH:

Please make sure you already have openssl compiled and installed in specific directory say /opt/usr/openssl and this has subdirectory like bin, lib, include etc that has openssl binary, libraries and header files.

Issue the following command from your build server linux machine, openssh working directory

bash-3.2$ pwd

/home/xxxxxx/projects/openssh/openssh-8.2p1

bash-3.2$ CC=ppc_6xx-gcc PATH=$PATH:/opt/eldk/ppc-v42-1/usr/bin ./configure --with-security-key-builtin --with-md5-passwords  --with-ssl-dir=/opt/usr/openssl --prefix=/opt/usr/openssh

...

...

...

Host: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
          Compiler: ppc_6xx-gcc
    Compiler flags: -g -O2 -pipe -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wuninitialized -Wsign-compare -Wformat-security -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -ftrapv -fno-builtin-memset -fstack-protector-all -std=gnu99 -fPIE
Preprocessor flags: -I/opt/usr/include  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE
      Linker flags: -L/opt/ust/openssl/lib  -Wl,-z,retpolineplt -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,noexecstack -fstack-protector-all -pie
         Libraries: -lresolv -lcrypto -lrt -ldl -lutil -lz  -lcrypt

bash-3.2$

bash-3.2$ make